# Weird Visual Studio behaviour? Can this be changed?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reference

I've got a stock standard visual studio 2008 solution with 3 class library projects. Nothing in them - even the default class1.cs file has been deleted.

The first thing I do is open up the References then delete all of them except Core, System and System.Core.

I then add a new class, which creates Class1.cs.

Now, System.Data and System.Xml have been added to the references again. Why? Is there any way i can stop this from happening?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is- [see this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ansonh/archive/2006/02/22/537414.aspx). By default those references get added back in when you add the class.

Comment: No worries- an interesting question.